# How to differentiate cos(x) where x is in steradians?

Tags: derivatives, solid-angle

Its been long time I did some differentiation, nevertheless I went through the basic differentiation of all trigonometric functions but couldn't understand why the differentiation of $cos(x)$ is $2 \pi sin(x)$, where $x$ is in **Steradians**. Please let me if I am missing something or let me know the right way to understand it. Many thanks.

Edit: Here is the expression I am talking about. It's actually a formula for solid angle.

$d$ = $(d/^2) _0$  = $2  sin_1 d_1 _0$.
[Here is the picture describing the parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8KAY.png)

Comment: A steradian is a solid angle, so $\cos(x)$ is undefined if $x$ is in steradians.

Comment: How do you define $\cos(x)$ when $x$ is a steradian?

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, yes $cos(x)$ couldn't be defined in case of Steradians. I added a picture of a spherical cone, where the a differential area is taken and integrated over the solid angle. Please have a look at it and the formula which I added in Edit. I am trying to figure out how the derivative of the  area is obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula you have is for the solid angle between $x$ and $x + \varepsilon_1$, where $\varepsilon_1$ is like $dx$.  The $2\pi $ comes from integrating around the azimuthal angle.